# Stargazer - using lapply to do mutliple linear regression models and store them in a list in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression, stargazer

`df` is data with values from 1-10 for 14 different variables formatted as a `dataframe` with n observations with lots of NA values for each variable which is why I couldn't do a regular `lm` with multiple predictors.

Then I used an `lapply` in order to do a linear regression for each variable because an `MLR` returns too many errors

```
x = lapply(df[,-1], function(x) summary(lm(df$IV ~ x)))
```

this returns a large list made up of 13 elements that are all lists

```
is.recursive(x) = TRUE
```

then I try to use stargazer

```
stargazer(x)
```

returns error

`Error in .summary.object$coefficients : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

how do i get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `summary` call so that `x` is a list of `lm` objects, not `summary.lm` objects.